# adding undefined characters to HTML

Tags: html, utf-8

I'm trying to add some alien characters to my website but I know that the UTF-8 won't understand it, is there any way I can do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: "alien characters", what do you mean ?

Comment: well, they are some characters that I designed and supposed to be an alien language.